# Google tag manager do not override object when setting new in loop

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I would like to set multiple objects in an array to store them in local storage.

But when I loop over an array and want to set the propeties and values of the object it only stores the last value. Which is logical but how can I store both of them objects in an array with same properties without creating a new object.

Here below the code:

```
for (var test in tests) {
  if (typeof localStorageObj === "undefined" && typeof localStorageArray === "undefined") {
    var localStorageObj = {};
    var localStorageArray = [];
  }

  localStorageObj.id = tests[test].id;
  localStorageArray.push(localStorageObj);
  console.log(localStorageObj, localStorageArray);
  localStorage.setItem('gtmTest', JSON.stringify(localStorageArray));
}
```

Keep in mind that google tag manager doesn't supports es6 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's kinda weird you do everything in the loop. Why don't you declare your variables before the loop?

Second of all, why don't u push your data after the loop?

I guess your mistake lies here:

```
   if(typeof localStorageObj === "undefined" && typeof localStorageArray === "undefined"){ 
       var localStorageObj = {};
       var localStorageArray = [];
   }
```

Can u try this?

```
var localStorageObj = {};
var localStorageArray = [];
for(var test in tests){
   localStorageObj.id = tests[test].id;
   localStorageArray.push(localStorageObj);
}
console.log(localStorageObj, localStorageArray);
 localStorage.setItem('gtmTest', JSON.stringify(localStorageArray));
```

Comment: You are right about declaring the variables outside the loop. But this does exactly the same and will override the object.id